# Linux: how swap is reported by free/top. How to determine correctly swap usage by process

Tags: partitioning, swap

Can somebody please explain how swap is reported in Linux?

I'm asking this because free and top commands reports some swap used that cannot be found in `/proc/$PID/status`.

`grep --color VmSwap /proc/*/status` reports `0 kB`.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel can make use of the swap area, you are only checking process usage.

One example is the tmpfs file system which is using the virtual memory as back-end. Should your RAM is exhausted, it will use some swap.